# Retrieve email id configured on iOS device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is this possible to retrieve email id configured on iOS device

Comment: What if there's more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a project on GitHub which uses public API's from apple to achieve this. It is showing the leaks, so I don't know how long it is going to work.. I tried to find it, but I cannot find it so fast on my MacBook. If I find it, I will post you the link... But it's on GitHub for sure!

Answer (score 1):

if you intend to fetch the email id from native "Mail" application, it is not possible by any of the public APIs available through iOS SDK.

Comment: https://github.com/0xced/ABGetMe here is the link for project that I found on github...It is using private APS...I am not sure whether it will approve by app store or not. Please let me your thoughts on this.

Comment: mentioned in the 
Limitations:
ABGetMe is not legally App Store compliant because it uses undocumented APIs which is proscribed by clause 3.3.1 of the iPhone Developer Program License Agreement. It is technically App Store compliant though as it will pass the App Store validation. Moreover, it should not crash even if the undocumented APIs change in the future.

the way it is described in my Opinion, appstore wont accept it.

and here is the famous remail: http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone sure this one didn't make to the appstore as well.

Comment: It means there are ways but they will not be approved by app store. thanks.